# How to execute multiple SQL scripts in a single file from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to execute multiple SQL scripts in a single file from C#. In between the scripts I have `GO` statements. the script is like an incremental script and day by day that script will increase. I tried using `ExecuteReader()`, `ExecuteScalar()` and `ExecuteNonQuery()`, but it was throwing exception saying `GO` is incorrect syntax.

I then split the script with `GO` and in a loop, I tried to execute there also where ever script will have `Declare @xyz DataType` it throwing an exception.

Please suggest how I can execute such script from C#.

```
foreach (var sqlBatch in ScriptDetails.Split(new[] { "GO", "Go", "go", "gO" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    try
    {
        string[] prefixes = { "--", "/*" };
        bool resultchk = prefixes.Any(prefix => sqlBatch.StartsWith(prefix));
        if (!resultchk)
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = sqlBatch;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();//ExecuteReader(); ExecuteScalar()
            connection.Close();
            Result.Add(new SQLResult { Final_message = "Success" });
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Result.Add(new SQLResult { Final_message = ex.Message.ToString(), Line_No = ex.LineNumber });
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `SMO` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: SMO are an additional effort to deploy (especially when you have to support different SQL Server versions). I wouln't use SMO just to run SQL Scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to open the connection only once to run all the parts of the script.

Pseudo-code:

```
use (var connection ...)
{
  connection.Open();
  foreach (var sqlBatch in ...)
  {
    use (var command = new Command(..., connection))
    {
      command.CommandText = sqlBatch;
      ...
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also a transaction implementation might be helpful. Just a thought. ;-)

Comment: @shadow: Hard to say. Most scripts are doing transaction themselves. But it's certainly a good point to consider.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan Steinegger